# How to simplify $x^{x^{-5}(5)}=5^{-\frac{25}{\sqrt[5]{5^{16}}}}$ and find a value from it?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

The problem is as follows:

First simplify:

$$x^{x^{-5}(5)}=5^{-\frac{25}{\sqrt[5]{5^{16}}}}$$

Then using $x$ find: $x^{-50}$

The alternatives in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&5\\
2.&\frac{1}{5}\\
3.&25\\
4.&125\\
\end{array}$

I'm confused about solving this problem, how should it be approached?

$x^{x^{-5}(5)}=5^{-\frac{25}{\sqrt[5]{5^{16}}}}$

$5^{-\frac{25}{\sqrt[5]{5^{16}}}}=5^{-\frac{1}{5\sqrt[5]{5}}}$

$5^{-\frac{1}{5\sqrt[5]{5}}}=5^{-\frac{1}{5^{\frac{6}{5}}}}$

But that's where I'm stuck. Where to go from there?. I can't seem to find a way to get that problematic $x$. Can someone help me with the radical manipulation?. Does this requires any additional multiplication?

Comment: First simplify the power of five: $-\frac{25}{\sqrt[5]{5^{16}}}=-5^{2-\tfrac{16}{5}}=-5^{-\tfrac65}$

Answer (score 2):

Im slightly confused about your notation, do you mean:
$$x^{5x^{-5}}$$ or:
$$\left(x^{x^{-5}}\right)^5$$

---

Anyways, we can start with the other side, we have:
$$5^{-\frac{25}{\sqrt[5]{5^{16}}}}\tag{1}$$
if we look at the power first:
$$-\frac{25}{\sqrt[5]{5^{16}}}=-\frac{5^2}{(5^{16})^{1/5}}=-\frac{5^2}{5^{16/5}}=-5^{2-16/5}=-5^{-6/5}$$
so we can simplify $(1)$ to:
$$5^{-5^{-6/5}}$$
now equate the LHS to this

Comment: Did you want to write a comment?

Comment: @VIVID I am in the process of completing this answer

Comment: @HenryLee I did simplified as you had suggested but I'm confused about equating it to the left side of the equation. By the way I wrote as it is indicated in the original source. But I believe the intended approach was to be the first line you had wrote.

Comment: @HenryLee I'm stuck. Don't both expressions I mean the first line you had wrote and the second line mean the same?. Can you help me finish this?.